# Is there a way to exclude specific file types from a directory comparision using python

Tags: python, directory

Here is what I have:

```
import filecmp
from filecmp import dircmp
def print_right_only(dcmp):
     for name in dcmp.right_only:
         print "%s not found in %s but found in %s" % (name, dcmp.left,
            dcmp.right)
     for sub_dcmp in dcmp.subdirs.values():
         print_right_only(sub_dcmp)

dcmp = dircmp('E:\GIS', 'J:\GIS') 
print_right_only(dcmp)
```

This works exactly as needed. I would like to be able to filter or exclude *.lock files from the results. I did see an ignore function related to `dircmp`, but could not get it to return any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dircomp`'s `ignore` doesn't take globs, only literals.

It wouldn't be that hard to fix by replacing `filecmp._filter` with:

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch
def _filter(flist, skip):
    return [item for item in flist 
                 if not any(fnmatch(item, pat) for pat in skip)]
filecmp._filter = _filter
```

Do this before you call `dircmp` and then `dircmp(..., ignore=['*.lock'])` would work as expected.

Untested.

Comment: Technically, `ignore` only looks at `object.__contains__`.  You could create a custom "container" where `__contains__` checks against a glob or regular expression.  I think that would be a little less hacky than overriding an implementation detail (but still hacky).

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the filtering after the fact?

```
import filecmp
from filecmp import dircmp
def print_right_only(dcmp):
     for name in dcmp.right_only:

         if name.endswith('.lock'):  # Check if it is a lock file.
             continue

         print "%s not found in %s but found in %s" % (name, dcmp.left,
            dcmp.right)
     for sub_dcmp in dcmp.subdirs.values():
         print_right_only(sub_dcmp)

dcmp = dircmp('E:\GIS', 'J:\GIS') 
print_right_only(dcmp)
```